# Como muestro el contenido de dos tablas con llave foranea en Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un problema a la hora de querer mostrar datos en un CRUD para usuarios. La tabla usuarios tiene como llave foránea el id de la tabla docente.
Este es el modelo User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'iddocente', 'email', 'rol', 'password'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function docente(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Docente');
}
}
```

Y este es el modelo Docente:

```
class Docente extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
    'nip', 'nombres', 'apellidos', 'dui', 'nit', 'especialidad'
];

public function grados(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Grado');
}

public function asignaturas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asignatura');
}

public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
}
```

En el controlador estoy tratando de hacer que el listado de usuarios muestre el docente al que se le asigno ese usuario y según algunos tutoriales lo hacen con la funcion each() y lo implementan de esta manera:

```
public function index(){
    $users=User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
    $users->each(function($users){
        $users->docente;
    });
```

Yo lo he implementado de esa forma y me da error en la vista index.blade.php que es donde quiero mostrar esa tabla. El error es el siguiente:

> (2/2) ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object

La vista es la siguiente: index.blade.php

```
@extends('templates.main')

@section('title', 'Listado de Usuarios')

@section('content')
<a href="{{ route('usuarios.create') }}" class="btn btn-info">Registrar       nuevo usuario</a><hr>
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <th>Docente</th>
        <th>Correo electrónico</th>
        <th>Rol</th>
        <th>Acción</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $user->docente->nombres }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->rol }}</td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas eliminar   este docente?')" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon- remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> 
                <a href="#"  class="btn btn-warning"><span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"  aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

@endsection
```

Comment: Cómo estás llamando a la vista en el index()? Si puedes agregar el código de la vista sería de ayuda.

Comment: La vista la estoy llamando asi: `return view('administracion.usuarios.index')->with('users', $users);`

Comment: ¿cuál es el código completo del método index() en el controlador?

Comment: `public function index(){
     $users=User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
     $users->each(function($users){
      $users->docente;
     });
     return view('administracion.usuarios.index')->with('users', $users);
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba usando el método "with" de Eloquent

```
public function index(){
    $users = User::with('docente')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```

UPDATE

Especifica el nombre de la columna `iddocente` en la relación `belongsTo`

```
public function docente(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Docente', 'iddocente');
}
```

Remueve la llamada al método each

Comment: Y en la vista como pondría el campo de la tabla docentes que quiero mostrar, así como ya lo tengo o cambiaria, hablo del foreach especificamente

Comment: Así funciono, ya muestra lo que necesito, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes precargar la relación `docente` con [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), con el método `with()` y de esta forma evitar el problema de N + 1:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('docente')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);

    return view('administracion.usuarios.index', compact('users'));
}
```

En teoría el código que tienes en la vista debería funcionar.

Comment: Pues siempre da el mismo error, lo probe con la funcion dd(), y en la parte que dice "relations" me aparece `"docente"=>null` y si hay datos en la base.

Comment: Algo estás haciendo mal al definir la relación, ¿cuál es la llave primaria de User y de Docente? ¿qué tablas utilizas? No las veo en el modelo.